# Python: JPEGs from folder to a Multipage-PDF with img2pdf

Tags: python, img2pdf

I'm an newbie and I'm trying to create a multipage pdf with img2pdf (recursive), but only the last picture is saved in a pdf file.

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import img2pdf

main_dir = Path(Path.cwd(),'MAIN')

for subfolder in main_dir.iterdir():
if subfolder.is_file():
    continue
    
    for filename in subfolder.iterdir():
        #pdf as foldername
        pdf_name = os.path.basename(subfolder)
        #write image-file to pdf file
        with open(pdf_name+".pdf", "wb") as f:
                f.write(img2pdf.convert(str(filename)))
```

When I test it with *print(filename)* all images are going through the loop.

Maybe someone can tell me where my misconception is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`img2pdf` module can directly take a list of image file names as an argument and converts them into pdf. Take a look at the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/) here

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import img2pdf


main_dir = Path(Path.cwd(),'your/path/to/images/folder')

for subfolder in main_dir.iterdir():
    imgs = []

    if subfolder.is_file():
        continue

    for filename in subfolder.iterdir():
        imgs.append(os.path.join(subfolder, filename))

    pdf_name = os.path.basename(subfolder)

    with open(pdf_name+".pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(img2pdf.convert(imgs))
```

Comment: thx for your answer @vignesh ...

I tried "ab" before but even then only the last picture is saved. 
It is strange, however, that the memory size corresponds to that of all images.

Comment: check the modified answer